# New blueberry bushes in bloom, should I snip flowers?

Tags: blueberries

Last week I planted 5 blueberry bushes (3 Duke, 2 Chandler) 32 inches apart. I mixed peat moss with the original clay soil and topped with mulch. I've read that (paraphrasing) "If you plant 2-year old blueberry bushes, you'll want to pick off any flowers that form a year or two after planting".

I'm not sure how old my bushes are and the greenhouse worker didn't either.  They are pretty big, so I'm skeptical about them being 2 years old.  They are about 4-5 feet tall and 2 feet wide.

Question :

Should I snip the flowers on the plants or should I just enjoy the small crop of blueberries this summer?

Answer (score -1):

I say eat them. Enjoy! Your blueberry bush sounds big enough to handle growing a small crop of berries. Make sure to prune in late winter/early spring though as that will encourage growth.